# Hay alguna forma que los datos ingresados en un .txt en python se guarden permanentemente?

Tags: python

La idea fue crear un archivo y guardar las demas variable con "append", mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera de guardarlos permanentemente por mas que se cierre el programa. Adjuntos captura y codigo.

```
def guardarstock():
    
    Verstock = int(input("Ingrese un 1 si quiere ver el stock o un 0 para salir: "))
    global codigoprod1, producto1, stringcantstock, stringV, opc

    while Verstock != 0:
        if Verstock != 0:
            print("Codigo   | producto   | cantidad de stock   | Valor por unidad")

        archstock = open ("Stockmercaderia.txt" , "w")
        archstock.write(codigoprod1)
        archstock.close()

        archstock = open ("Stockmercaderia.txt" , "a")
        archstock.write (producto1)
        archstock.close()

        archstock = open ("Stockmercaderia.txt" , "a")
        archstock.write (stringcantstock)
        archstock.close()

        archstock = open ("Stockmercaderia.txt" , "a")
        archstock.write (stringV)
        archstock.close()

        archstock = open ("Stockmercaderia.txt" , "r")
        archstock.read()
        archstock.close()

        print(" ",codigoprod1, "    " ,producto1, "         " ,stringcantstock, "                " ,stringV)

        Verstock = int(input("Ingrese un 1 si quiere ver el stock o un 0 para salir: "))
        if Listadodepedidos == "1":
            Listadodepedidos()
        else:
            MenuPrincipal()
```

[image: Imagen del .py]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo es que en tu código estás haciendo de una forma que sobrescribe el archivo en lugar de agregar nuevos datos a él.

Aqui una posible solución:

```
class Stock:
    def __init__(self, codigo, producto, cantidad, valor):
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.producto = producto
        self.cantidad = cantidad
        self.valor = valor

    def mostrar_stock(self):
        print(f"{self.codigo}    {self.producto}         {self.cantidad}                {self.valor}")

    @staticmethod
    def mostrar_stock_titulo():
        print("Codigo   | producto   | cantidad de stock   | Valor por unidad")

def guardar_stock(archivo, stocks):
    with open(archivo, "w") as f:
        for stock in stocks:
            f.write(f"{stock.codigo},{stock.producto},{stock.cantidad},{stock.valor}\n")

def cargar_stock(archivo):
    stocks = []
    try:
        with open(archivo, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                codigo, producto, cantidad, valor = line.strip().split(",")
                stock = Stock(codigo, producto, cantidad, valor)
                stocks.append(stock)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("El archivo de stock no existe. Se creará uno nuevo.")
    return stocks

def agregar_producto(stocks):
    codigo = input("Ingrese el código del producto: ")
    producto = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")
    cantidad = input("Ingrese la cantidad de stock: ")
    valor = input("Ingrese el valor por unidad: ")

    nuevo_stock = Stock(codigo, producto, cantidad, valor)
    stocks.append(nuevo_stock)

    print("Producto agregado con éxito.")

archivo_stock = "stock.txt"

# Cargar el stock desde el archivo si existe
stocks = cargar_stock(archivo_stock)

while True:
    Verstock = int(input("Ingrese 1 para ver el stock, 2 para agregar un producto o 0 para salir: "))

    if Verstock == 0:
        break

    if Verstock == 1:
        Stock.mostrar_stock_titulo()  # Mostrar el título una vez
        for stock in stocks:
            stock.mostrar_stock()

    if Verstock == 2:
        agregar_producto(stocks)

# Guardar el stock en el archivo
guardar_stock(archivo_stock, stocks)

# Aquí puedes agregar la lógica adicional dependiendo de lo que desees hacer con la lista de pedidos y el menú principal.
```

Comment: Hola, buenos días, lo probé y funciono, ahora como hago para que los nuevos datos se bajen a la próxima linea ? a donde tendría que colocar el \n, y luego si quiero volver a ver el stock me sale error  . Muchas gracias

Comment: Luego si quiero ver lo cargado directamente desde ese menú, me sale error que no defini el valor en (codprod1), otra pregunta seria como ver lo cargado en el archivo sin tener que cargar otra vez todo por mas que cierre el programa. Gracias

Comment: Hola, actualice el código.